# Can't expand newly created Open Extension in MS Graph

Tags: azure-active-directory

TLDR version: This was caused by not encoding the Graph query string before calling Graph - not an API issue!

I've created a new Open Extension for a particular user. I can read the user, or the Open Extension specifically, but I can't use $expand to return the user with the Open Extension together in a single call.

I'm using Application authentication to AAD (with a secret), and that may or may not have something to do with it. Every example I've found uses the /v1.0/me shortcut in Graph Explorer.

**EDIT: I quickly got an answer that did not take this into account. The MS Graph Explorer only allows for authentication via a user account and does not help me**

I can consistently add, read and delete an extension. The only issue is expanding the extensions attributes when reading.

```
$uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/user@domain.com.au/extensions"

$body = '{
    "@odata.type":"microsoft.graph.openTypeExtension",
    "extensionName":"au.com.domain.customAttributes",
    "shoesize":"large"
}'

$query = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $uri -ContentType "application/json" -Body $body -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $token"} -ErrorAction Stop

#Modify an existing custom attribute
$uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/user@domain.com.au/extensions/au.com.domain.customAttributes"

$body = '{
    "shoesize":"small"
}'

$query = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Patch -Uri $uri -ContentType "application/json" -Body $body -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $token"} -ErrorAction Stop

## Read user without extension attributes
$uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/user@domain.com.au"
$user = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $uri -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $token"} -ErrorAction Stop
Write-Host $user

## Read extension attributes only in separate call
$uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/user@domain.com.au/extensions/au.com.domain.customAttributes"
$customAttributes = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $uri -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $token"} -ErrorAction Stop
Write-Host $customAttributes

## Delete a custom extention
$uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/user@domain.com.au/extensions/au.com.domain.customAttributes"
$customAttributes = Invoke-RestMethod -Method DELETE -Uri $uri -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $token"} -ErrorAction Stop

Write-Host $customAttributes
```

I need to be able to use a filter to get 100 users from 55000, **including** all of their open extension attributes.

EDIT: I suspect this may be a query parameters related problem and I think I'll sleep on this before rewriting the question maybe?

This works for example:

```
$uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users"
$users = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $uri -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $token"}  -ContentType "application/json" -ErrorAction Stop
```

This gives me the first 100 users for my tenant. Adding any query parameter at all breaks the request. I get a 400 error, even if example the same Graph call in Graph Explorer gives a meaningful response.

I'm using Invoke-RestMethod in powershell to make the calls to Graph... I suspect I need to try a different way of making calls or try passing extra parameters to Invoke-RestMethod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but I can't use $expand to return the user with the Open Extension
>   together in a single call

Extensions show up in Microsoft Graph within the Extensions collection. So you can use $expand to return the users with the Open Extension together in a single call.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$expand=extensions
```

I created the same extension for a user. I can find it in the response.

[image]

**Update:**

I tried with client credential flow, it also works. Here are the detailed steps.

1. Register an application and grant User.ReadWrite.All permission, remember to grant admin consent.

[image]

2.get access token

[image]

3.call the api with access token

[image]

**Update:** run it using powershell

[image]

Comment: But sending URI:  "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/user@domain.com.au?$expand=extensions" gives me a bad request. I may not have been clear in the question but I did try using $expand. Are you authenticating via secret in your environment?

Comment: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/user@domain.com.au?$expand=extensions gives a 400 error (bad request).

Comment: @DavidVernon You can not specify the user here, try with `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$expand=extensions`

Comment: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$expand=extensions gives a 400 error also! I am authenticating using an application and I have made sure the app has the user.readwriteall.all as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Comment: @DavidVernon I tried with client credential flow and it also works, see my update answer.

Comment: Definitely getting closer. My app is definitely created and it has the write permission added. I am still getting a 400 response though... Did you write the open extension using the exact JSON I have? Maybe I am doing the read correctly, but the write incorrectly? I have seen examples online where a bad write throws no error until the value is read back.

Comment: @DavidVernon Yes, I used the json you provide.

Comment: @DavidVernon How did you get the access token?

Comment: Sitting down to troubleshoot. Re token it's the same token used to write shoesize, which is written and read. Powershell to get it:  $uri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token"

$body = @{
    client_id     = $clientId
    scope         = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
    client_secret = $clientSecret
    grant_type    = "client_credentials"
}

$tokenRequest = Invoke-WebRequest -Method Post -Uri $uri -ContentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -Body $body -UseBasicParsing
$token = ($tokenRequest.Content | ConvertFrom-Json).access_token

Comment: @DavidVernon I just tried it in powershell. You need to url encode the '$' in the url. `$uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?%24expand=extensions"`. See my updated answer.

Comment: Yes, this was a URL encoding issue all along! THANK YOU! Name your currency next time you're in Melbourne!